# Trouble having an SVG rectangle changing colors

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, svg

So essentially I am a complete noob to SVG, Javascript and CSS, all of which I need for this project. Essentially what I am trying to do is have a rectangle change colors when it is clicked on. Right now my JS code is

```
let monday = document.getElementById("monOn");

monday.onclick = function(e) {
  monday.setAttribute("fill","red");
  console.log("click");
}
```

Every thing checks out and the console will log when I click.

My SVG code to set up the rectangle is

```
<svg class="background">
  <rect id="monOn" pointer-events="visible" fill="blue" />  
</svg>
```

When I click however, it spits out an error that says "TypeError: Expected a function"

I understand what the error message means, but from everything I've seen the changeAttribute() function does not require a function.

As a side note, I was wondering how I can set a button up in SVG rather than just a rect.

Any help is welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Your code seems to be working. Can you provide a live example?

Comment: @Azametzin There's really nothing else I think there is worth showing. If I need to, I can record a video, but I feel like it warrants mentioning that the action is part of a Fitbit app using the Fitbit SDK, so maybe it's something weird with that?

Comment: I mean. I was not able to reproduce the issue. When I create a snippet with your code, it works as expeceted. Are you able to create a live example showing the error happening?

Comment: @Azametzin I recorded a little video. I tried to include anything I felt was pertinent. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T0BQome-NF0m0tzyqYANQNVFJxNOep0u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry. It's hard to understand what is happening there. The code seems ok and my tests don't show anything different. What I would try to do is to change ``monday.onclick`` for ``monday.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })``, but I'm not sure it will solve it at all. Maybe you can get some help from fitbit community, since it looks like a specific issue from their product.